How to update SSHFS cache?
if i use an sshfs mount with dir_cache=yes and a very high dcache_timeout (like 4 weeks or longer), how to force an update of this cache when things are changed at the remote host without having to remount? I'm talking about a 160TB mount, so its quite a lot of data. Caching without polling makes no sense tbh, only if the host does not have changes within the timeout interval. Any hints?
Regards
